# Can two textarea elements be "linked" to the same native input events instead of copying the value upon each addEventListener input event?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to "link" two `textarea` elements to the same native input events? I know that I can set the `value` of one to that of the other; and read that this can be done with a pseudo element also at [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-cleanest-trick-for-autogrowing-textareas/) but each method appears to rewrite the entire string from the "active" textarea to the "copy" textarea on each key event.

Is there a way to just link them like a split view of the same file in a text editor? I don't really know how that works in a text editor but I've been working in some large files in split view and it would seem quite odd that they update the entire contents on each key event as opposed to just linking them together.

Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: HTML is a markup language as opposed to an actual computer language.  I doubt this is possible.  You can of course input in one textarea and have the text appear in another through javascript but this is more like a copy and paste procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to "link" two textarea elements to the same native input events?

No, you need to add such logic yourself (or use a library like [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/examples/split/))

> I don't really know how that works in a text editor but I've been working in some large files in split view and it would seem quite odd that they update the entire contents on each key event as opposed to just linking them together.

Yes, they likely have some more advanced techniques. For advanced UIs, you most of the time have something like a Model-View-Controler (or similar) concept. Where you can have multiple views, and those views are only informed about what has changed.

And all methods that do splitview/mirroring in "HTML" likely don't use `<textarea>` but [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) because the information you get about changes in a `textarea` is very limited, you basically only get the information that something changed but not where and what.

For `contenteditable` you could use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), to pass changes from one `contenteditable` to another, but the logic still has to be done by you.

> I know that I can set the value of one to that of the other

That's basically the only option you have for `<textarea>`.

Comment: Thank you. The link to CodeMirror is quite interesting. Do you know if they are really dispatching a keyboard event to be triggered on the second textarea for an event that took place in the first textarea? I didn't think that was permitted but, perhaps, the first key event is considered sufficient user action to trigger it as isTrusted on the second.